# Resizing UIPopover and its UITableView programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a UIPopoverController which loads with a custom controller which is a subclass of UITableViewController. It serves to present a number of suggestions, under a search bar.

When my popover opens the UITableView inside it show as many rows as possible; the first ones show the choices I set up, the last ones are blank. What I am trying to achieve is showing just N number of rows (corresponding to the choices I am offering), and getting rid of the empty cells at the bottom.

I have been trying a number of different techniques: I have been assigning a custom frame in viewWillAppear:animated and in viewDidAppear:animated; I have been fiddling with the autoresizing properties in IB; I can't use init or viewDidLoad because the table content is dynamic.

I am quite sure that I'm being dumb here, there msut be an easy way to accomplish this.
Any suggestion?
Cheers,
Davide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the number of rows that will appear in the table by using the UITableViewDataSourceProtocol method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

More on this is covered in the documentation found here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Basically, you simply return the following inside the method:

numberOfRowsInSection {

if (section == someSection) {
    if (row == someRow) {
        return thisManyRows;
    }
}

Hope this helps :)